# jQuery - convert text to google maps link

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps

I need to get address from table and create link from it. I want to replace text inside `th` element with `mapaLink`.

1) mapaLink - `<a>` element should contains `mapaText` as a link text

2) href should direct to google maps and find that address

```
var mapa = $('th').filter(function(index) { return $(this).text() === "Address"; }).next("td"),
    mapaText = mapa.text(),
    mapaLink = $("<a />", {
    target: "_blank",
    href : "http://www.google.com/",
});
```

codepen is here http://codepen.io/anon/pen/jqyPbN?editors=0010

Answer (score 0):

```
$('th:contains("Address")').each(function() {
    var targetElem = $(this).next();
  var createStr = '<a target="_blank" href="http://www.google.com/maps/search/'+targetElem.text()+'">'+targetElem.text()+'</a>';
    $(this).next().html(createStr);
});
```

check the above piece of code, with working [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/53tu7whb/), use of `contains` will solve your issue, know more about [`:contains()`](https://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/)

Answer (score 0):

The google maps search URL schema is `https://www.google.com/maps/search/{your search}`.

So, you replace the texts with links, you just find it in each row, then create a link according the schema and that's it.

```js
$('th:contains(Address)').each(function(index) {
  var $this = $(this),
      mapa = $this.next(),
      mapaText = mapa.text(),
      mapaLink = $("<a />", {
        target: "_blank",
        href: 'https://www.google.com/maps/search/' + mapaText,
        text: mapaText
      });    
  
  mapa.html('').append(mapaLink);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Address</th>
    <td>New York</td>
  </tr>  
  <tr>
    <th>Address</th>
    <td>Miami</td>
  </tr>  
</table>
```

http://output.jsbin.com/qotugi

Answer (score 0):

you can try something like this

```
var mapa = $('th').filter(function(index) {
  return $(this).text() === "Address"; 
}).next("td");


$(mapa).each(function(index) {

  var mapaText = $(this).text();
  var mapaLink = $("<a />", {
    target: "_blank",
    href : "https://www.google.co.uk/maps/search/" + mapaText
  }).html(mapaText);

  $(this).html(mapaLink);
});
```

https://plnkr.co/edit/q2mhY5AjWBgVBB96wuF7